# ImportError /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: version `gLIB _2.4' not found

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-import, importerror

I am currently getting an import error and it seems to happen on the requests module in python. Here is the error I am getting on my RPi

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pathfinderAllocator.py", line 4, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.7.egg/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.7.egg/requests/utils.py", line 15, in <module>
    import io
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: version `gLIB▒_2.4' not found (required by /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so)
```

I have tried going to that directory and I can see that /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 exists.  I then tried to do a ldd on /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so which then came back saying that there were some missing files?

```
ldd /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: version `gLIB▒_2.4' not found (required by /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so)
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `gLIB▒_2.4' not found (required by /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so)
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: version `gLIB▒_2.4' not found (required by /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so)
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x7efc4000)
        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so (0x76f3f000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0x76f07000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0x76dca000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x76d9d000)
        /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x54ae7000)
```

I only have one installation of python on my pi and that's python 2.7

here is my libc6 version

```
Package: libc6
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Multi-Arch: same
Version: 2.19-18+deb8u1
Priority: required
Section: libs
Maintainer: GNU Libc Maintainers <debian-glibc@lists.debian.org>
Architecture: armhf
Uncompressed Size: 9,000 k
Depends: libgcc1
Suggests: glibc-doc, debconf | debconf-2.0, locales
Conflicts: prelink (<= 0.0.20090311-1), tzdata (< 2007k-1), tzdata-etch
Breaks: hurd (< 1:0.5.git20140203-1), libtirpc1 (< 0.2.3), locales (< 2.19), locales-all (< 2.19), nscd (< 2.19)
Description: GNU C Library: Shared libraries
 Contains the standard libraries that are used by nearly all programs on the system. This package includes shared versions of the standard C library and the standard math library, as well as many
 others.
Homepage: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html
```

I have also tried using sudo apt-get install glib2.0 which came back with

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-0-refdbg' for regex 'glib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-bin' for regex 'glib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-dbg' for regex 'glib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-cil' for regex 'glib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-dev' for regex 'glib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-doc' for regex 'glib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-cil-dev' for regex 'glib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libtaglib2.0-cil' for regex 'glib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libdbus-glib2.0-cil' for regex 'glib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libdbus-glib2.0-cil-dev' for regex 'glib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-data' for regex 'glib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-tests' for regex 'glib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-0' for regex 'glib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-0-dbg' for regex 'glib2.0'
libglib2.0-0 is already the newest version.
libglib2.0-0 set to manually installed.
libglib2.0-data is already the newest version.
libglib2.0-data set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglib2.0-bin : Depends: libelfg0 (>= 0.8.12) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: This is noch a problem with python but a problem with your os. You are missing the library gLib_2.4. Which OS is running on your RPi?

Comment: @MaximilianKindshofer I am running raspbian

Comment: Ok there should be a package called libc6 - you can see which version you have installed using sudo aptitude show libc6

Comment: @MaximilianKindshofer I have edited my post to contain the information you specified

Comment: does apt-get install glib2.0 solve the dependencies?

Comment: @MaximilianKindshofer No it didn't, again I have also re edited to contain what was printed on the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96033/discussion-between-maximilian-kindshofer-and-johnathon64).

Answer (score 1):

---

python2.7/`lib-dynload/_io.so` is a basic Python-2.7 file. Example :

```
 $ objdump -Dslx /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so  | grep -i gLIB
    0x0d696912 0x00 07 GLIBC_2.2
    0x0d696910 0x00 03 GLIBC_2.0
    0x0d696911 0x00 08 GLIBC_2.1
    0x0d696912 0x00 06 GLIBC_2.2
    0x09691f73 0x00 05 GLIBC_2.1.3
    0x0d696914 0x00 04 GLIBC_2.4
    0x0d696910 0x00 02 GLIBC_2.0
 203c 474c4942 435f322e 3200474c 4942435f  GLIBC_2.2.GLIBC_
 204c 322e3000 474c4942 435f322e 3100474c  2.0.GLIBC_2.1.GL
 205c 4942435f 322e312e 3300474c 4942435f  IBC_2.1.3.GLIBC_
```

The mystery here is that you seem to have a glibc = libc6 with no object by name GLIBC_2.4 .

And why was the Python-2.7 in your OS compiled with a different glibc ?

---